# Firefox - edit userchrome.css

Tags: firefox, userchrome.css

I recently switched to Firefox from Chrome and I love its performance (I enabled WenRender).
There's a little thing that I miss: in Chrome I'm able to right-click on a folder in the bookmark toolbar and select "open all in new window". I know I could do the same in FF by clicking shift and then right-click "open all in tabs" and a new windows would appear.
Is it possible to edit "userChrome.css" or "userContent.css" in order to edit the the right-click menu in FF and add that entry?
Thank you,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that isn't controlled by styles. It might be possible to [create a web-extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) to do that though.